# How to parallelize a function which has more than one parameter?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, simulation, cpu-cores

I have a particular simulation to perform which takes some time to run in R. Since I want to perform 1000 simulations, I decided to use "parallel" package to distribute these simulations over 4 cores. I know that I can get a resulting vector if I have a function like follows.

```
results_parallel <- parSapply(cl, c(1000,1000,1000,1000), rnorm)
```

In here rnorm() has only one parameter as the input, so that I can ask to produce 4000 values using 4 cores.

But my simulation has more than one parameter. My question is, since I have more than one parameter as input, how can I tell which parameter should be calculated using 4 cores? If `simulation1(A,B,C,m)` is my function where m is the number of simulations, I want to ask each core to to do the simulation 250 times, so that finally I can get 1000 simulations. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try creating a function wrapper that takes a single argument rather multiple ones.

```
rnorm1 <- function(ls){
  rnorm(n = ls$n, mean = ls$mean, sd = ls$sd)
}

cl <- makeCluster(2)

example_list <- list(
      list(n=1000, mean = 0, sd = 1),
      list(n=1000, mean = 1, sd = 2)
)

results_parallel <- parSapply(cl, example_list, rnorm1)
```

You would just have to specify the required list of arguments so that it is a list of lists.

Comment: That was really a good solution. I tries this and it worked well. Thanks.

Comment: If the solution answered your question, please make sure you mark it as accepted to help others find it in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're after, but you should be able to add the parameters to be passed to `rnorm` within your function call. I haven't used `parSapply` before, but here it is with `llply`:

```
doMC::registerDoMC( cores = 4 )
results <- plyr::llply( .data = c(1000,1000,1000,1000),
                        .fun = rnorm, mean = 1, sd = 0.4,
                        .parallel = T 
)
```

Note the parameters `mean` and `sd` being passed to `rnorm` from within the `llply` call. `parSapply` should be able to handle this in the same way. For example:

```
results_parallel <- parSapply( cl, 
                               X = c(1000,1000,1000,1000), 
                               FUN = rnorm, mean = 1, sd = 0.4 
)
```